# rx subscribeOn didn't work with Subject?

Tags: android, multithreading, system.reactive

here is the code:

```
Observable<Integer> observable = Observable.just(1, 2);
observable.doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Emitting " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
          .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
          .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Emitting " + i + " after subscribeOn" + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
          .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
          .subscribe(i -> System.out.println( "Receiving " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));
```

it gives me this output:

```
I/System.out: Emitting 1 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
I/System.out: Emitting 1 after subscribeOn on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
I/System.out: Emitting 2 on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
I/System.out: Emitting 2 after subscribeOn on thread RxComputationScheduler-1
I/System.out: Receiving 1 on thread main
I/System.out: Receiving 2 on thread main
```

all is okay.

Now i wanna to do same thing with Subject, i've changed the code as follows:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();

subject.doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Emitting " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
       .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
       .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Emitting " + i + " after subscribeOn" + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))
       .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
       .subscribe(i -> System.out.println( "Receiving " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

subject.onNext(1);
```

and in this case i get no output. Why so? And how i can force Subject emit flow in given Scheduler?

Comment: If RxJava is still anything like Rx.NET, then `.subscribeOn` will have no effect when used with a subject. i.e. there is no cost to subscription or code that is run when subscribing. However if your observable sequence when subscribed to say did some I/O and you wanted that to be performed on another thread (to prevent blocking the GUI), then `subscribeOn` would be useful, and you wouldn't be using a subject.

Comment: yeah, but i want to use Subject, coz it needed to start emitting the sequence from different parts of my app. Having subject will do this more simple rather then use Observable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

decision is:

```
PublishSubject<Integer> subject = PublishSubject.create();
subject
      **.observeOn(Schedulers.computation())**
      .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("Emitting " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()))                    
      .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
      .subscribe(i -> System.out.println( "Receiving " + i + " on thread " + Thread.currentThread().getName()));

subject.onNext(1);
```

or u can call subject.onNext(1) from Schedulers.computation() thread